# SwiftUI losing reference while trying to reuse a UIViewRepresentable on different views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to reuse a UIKit view on SwiftUI with a UIViewRepresentable.
Whenever i tap the representable i want to go to a fullScreenCover and reuse that same UIView.
Somehow, when i close the fullscreenView, the UIView is missing.
I've tried several approaches but i couldn't make it work,
Can some one point me in the right direction, is there something i'm missing to see?

[image: InitialLoad]
[image: Fullscreen]
[image: ReturnFromFullscreen]

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State var isFullscreen: Bool = false
   /// Array of UIView objects
   var uiViewArray: [CustomUIView] = [CustomUIView(text: "1"), CustomUIView(text: "2"), CustomUIView(text: "3")]
   let cardWidth: CGFloat = 200
   let cardHeight: CGFloat = 200
   
   @StateObject var viewManager = ViewManager()

   var body: some View {
       return VStack {
           ScrollView {
               ForEach(uiViewArray, id: \.id) { uiView in
                   LabelViewRepresentable(customUIView: uiView)
                       .frame(width: cardWidth,
                              height: cardHeight)
                       .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                           viewManager.selectedFullscreenView = uiView
                           isFullscreen.toggle()
                       }
               }
           }
       }
       .background(Color.gray)
       .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isFullscreen,
                     content: {
           FullScreenView(isFullscreen: $isFullscreen,
                          uiView: viewManager.selectedFullscreenView)
       })
    
   }
}
```

```
struct FullScreenView: View {
    @Binding var isFullscreen: Bool
    var uiView: CustomUIView?
         
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                isFullscreen.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Close")
            })
            if uiView != nil {
                LabelViewRepresentable(customUIView: uiView!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct LabelViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    var customUIView: CustomUIView
    
    init(customUIView: CustomUIView) {
        self.customUIView = customUIView
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomUIView {
       uiView.backgroundColor = .green
       return customUIView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CustomUIView, context: Context) { }
}
class CustomUIView: UIView {
    var text: String
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    
    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = .init(origin: .zero,
                            size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        label.text = self.text
        self.addSubview(label)
    }
    
    required init?(coder _: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class ViewManager: ObservableObject  {
    var selectedFullscreenView: CustomUIView?
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `@ObservedObject` where the object is owned -- use `@StateObject`

Comment: You are right, thanks! But still doesn't solve the issue, and the UIView is lost once you close the fullscreenCover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIView` can only be added once to a view hierarchy. Once it's added to the full screen view, it's taken out of the original hierarchy and it has no signal to add itself back in when the full screen view is dismissed.

You can avoid this issue by conditionally displaying it in the original `ScrollView`. Note that I've added a `Spacer` to take its space and preserve the scroll position while the real `UIView` is omitted from the hierarchy.

```
ForEach(uiViewArray, id: \.id) { uiView in
    Group {
        if !isFullscreen {
            LabelViewRepresentable(customUIView: uiView)
        } else {
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    .frame(width: cardWidth,
           height: cardHeight)
    .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
        viewManager.selectedFullscreenView = uiView
        isFullscreen.toggle()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`makeUIView` needs to init it, e.g.

```
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomUIView {
       let uiView = CustomUIView()
       uiView.backgroundColor = .green
       return uiView
    }
```

You also need to implement `updateUIView` to use the struct's vars to update the `uiView` with any changes, e.g.

```
let text: String

func updateUIView(_ uiView: CustomUIView, context: Context) {
    if uiView.text != text {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}
```

Think of the `UIViewRepresentable` like a configuration value that constantly changes and you use to update the same `UIView` object. SwiftUI keeps track of what `UIView` object to configure based on its position in the `View` hierarchy (called its identity) and passes it in to `updateUIView` so you don't need to hold onto it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and you are right the UIViewRepresentable is made to create the UIView on its own, but on this particular case i need to keep reference to the UIView outside the representable.

Comment: If that's the case then you should look into `UIHostingController` to host SwiftUI inside of your `UIKit` layer.